# Switch two panels in on

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I have got one J Frame that includes 2 panels , I was able to switch between them using Visible but I want them to appear in the same position and the same size the other was in.

Answer (score 1):

Use a CardLayout to swap JPanels. The tutorial can be found here: [CardLayout tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

When you do this, you will need a JPanel to be set to use the CardLayout and which will hold your other two JPanels. You will need to add these JPanels to the CardLayout using JPanel with String constants, so that the CardLayout will be able to identify the views with a String. For instance:

```
CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
JPanel cardHoldingPanel = new JPanel(cardLayout);

// .....
```

then when adding your two views to the above:

```
cardHoldingPanel.add(viewPanelOne, "one");
cardHoldingPanel.add(viewPanelTwo, "two");
```

Then to swap views, if all you have are the two JPanels, you could simply call `next(...)` on the CardLayout object

```
cardLayout.next(cardHoldingPanel);
```

To show a specific view, you would need the String constant used to add the view and call `show(...)` on the CardLayout object:

```
cardLayout.show(cardHoldingPanel, "one");
```